# Google Maps API - Drop a new pin

Tags: google-maps, drag-and-drop

I'd like users to be able to drop a pin on my custom Google Maps integration, similar to the ability to do this in the "My Maps" section on Google.  I can't find anything about allowing a user to drop new pins through the API though.  Can anyone provide some info or point me to the right direction?

Comment: see Google Maps API docs: [Saving User-Added Data with Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/info-windows-to-db)

Answer (score 22):

If you're using V3, a good example can be found at http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_click2add_infowindow.html. The tutorials at http://econym.org.uk/gmap/ are also a good place to start, and there are loads of useful links for V2 and V3 at http://www.geocodezip.com/.

Comment: Here is an other exemple, more basic. http://www.lotusmarketing.ca/misc/googlemap/

Comment: Hi @Sonia, could you please share your example code?

Answer (score 7):

While the other answers are helpful, I thought it good to add a simple code snippet for quick reference. Essentially you need to add an event listener to your map's init method, and within it, call `new google.maps.Marker`. For example:

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 41.763031, lng: -73.044465 },
        zoom: 17.75
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map,
        });
    });
}
```