# Allow user to place marker on a google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm looking for a way to allow a user to place a marker on a Google map and then get the co-ordinates so I can email them to a user.

Is it possible to allow users to do this on the fly? I've seen [here](http://marcelpad.wordpress.com/2007/12/11/adding-markers-on-google-maps/) and understand I can do this using longitude and Latitude. So using the above method can I get a Longitude and Latitude from a users click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478840/google-maps-api-drop-a-new-pin/3478987#3478987) older post is what you're looking for I think. Add in an ajax call with the lat/long and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using the following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){
  alert( "Latitude: "+event.latLng.lat()+" "+", longitude: "+event.latLng.lng() ); 
});
```

The `map` variable is your google.maps.Map instance. Every time the user clicks the map an alert box will display the coordinates of the place he clicked.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
alert(event.latLng.lat() + ", " + event.latLng.lng());
});

}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```