# Google Maps HTML5 click to get lat, long

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to build a mobile HTML5 webapp in which user can click on the map to get lat/long from Google Maps. Is there a code example? I tried googling but only found some website that does that but no soucecode example.

This is because I'm going to use HTML5 geolocation to display the current location first, but if it's not accurate then users can specify that by themselves.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm sure there are real tutorial sources out there, but you *could* also look into the sites' source code....

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The code below will show you how to get the Long and Lat when the user clicks the map - [Allow user to place marker on a google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916438/allow-user-to-place-marker-on-a-google-map)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){
  alert( "Latitude: "+event.latLng.lat()+" "+", longitude: "+event.latLng.lng() ); 
});
```

Comment: This is great. Kinda thought this was it from the Google Maps API reference. However, this event fires when you touch the map to move or position it (cursor becomes closed hand). Mousedown in other languages. How would you fire it on Mouse Up?

Answer (score 6):

I want to show you complete answere:

this is main part of the code the event is based on click and get Lat/Long with click and show it at **alert()**

> google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
>   alert(event.latLng.lat() + ", " + event.latLng.lng()); });

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
alert(event.latLng.lat() + ", " + event.latLng.lng());
});

}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

please change your API KEY

> src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap"

put your API KEY between **key=** and **&callback**:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= @@@@@@@ &callback=myMap

Comment: can you please suggest how to suggest all lat long with sub radius of given center.

Answer (score 3):

**You have to use event argument.**

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.latLng, map: map});
     console.log(event.latLng);   // Get latlong info as object.
     console.log( "Latitude: "+event.latLng.lat()+" "+", longitude: "+event.latLng.lng()); // Get separate lat long.
 });
```